# Simulate raspberry pi GPIO

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-3b+, emulation

Is there a software to simulate Raspberry Pi hardware design such as proteus? I would like :

- To use a raspberry pi as a virtual component,
- Do all the wiring, simulate,
- Simulate, test code,
- Check for errors and,
- Be able to the code implement on real hardware.

Is there such software?

Comment: Broadcom likely has some models for their chips, but they certainly won't give them to you for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the beta Microsoft emulator (https://azure-samples.github.io/raspberry-pi-web-simulator/), which only supports one built in circuit board, the only other emulator i could find is
http://www.rpi-emulator.com/ provides an offline downloadable RPi-3 emulator for windows systems.

> Raspberry Pi Emulator lets you emulate Raspberry Pi 3 hardware running a Raspbian system, inside your Windows system. It's ideal when you want to test your software and don't want to bother switching to actual Raspberry Pi hardware, or just want to take a quick look at what Raspbian looks like.
>   This program is just a wrapper for qemu system, as qemu has no gui, and it's main purpose is to save you time typing all those pesky arguments into the command line to get qemu started. You can still see the whole command used to run qemu so you can change anything to your liking prior to running it.
>   The emulator lets you chose the system image which will boot and ammount of RAM. Unfortunately current version of qemu doesn't support using more than 256MB RAM but that seems to be enough to run Raspbian anyway.
>   Since the image file boots directly without creating a virtual hard drive, it will have no free space for you to store your data, so it is recommended to expand it. This wrapper also has an option to do that.
>   Note: qemu doesn't work well with all Raspbian versions. Raspbian Stretch(2017-11-29) is tested and known to work, so I recommend you get it here: http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2017-12-01/

Comment: Sorry I cannot upvote as this is a new account :,)

Comment: No problem, however i have tested none of the solutions. also the up-vote is ok.

Comment: @TheCondorIV if the answer worked for you you should press the green tick to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3):

I found an online simulator here, but you can't modify the hardware: https://create.withcode.uk/python/A3

https://fritzing.org/ has hardware and code, but I have not tried the coding yet. It costs about $9 but is worth it in my opinion. They also have the option to create and upload your schematics and will send you a PCB board (for a fee).

Comment: It looks like this simulator only runs python scripts and has no documentation. Am I missing something?

Comment: It has an option to add a file, but I am not sure how it would work with different types of code. I also recently discovered https://fritzing.org/ which is not free, but the price is nominal. You can add hardware, but I have not tried the programming option. It does have a raspberry pi available.